# How to use a string as a name of array in python, so that this can be used in for-loops

Tags: python, arrays, string, for-loop

Let's say

```
t1=loadtxt("t\\1.txt")
t2=loadtxt("t\\2.txt")
```

Assume inside 1.txt is

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Assume also inside 2.txt is

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

#

```
t1[0,0]=1
t1[0,1]=2
t1[0,2]=3
t2[0,0]=1
t2[0,1]=2
t2[0,2]=3
st=0


for i in range(2):
    for j in range(3):
        a='t'+str(i+1)

        st=st+a
```

I got "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

What I want this piece of code to do is 
st=t1[0,0]+t1[0,1]+t1[0,2]+t2[0,0]+t2[0,1]+t2[0,2]

Then how to fulfill this goal?
How to represent the array name with regular numbers in for loop? Instead of summing each value one by one.

Comment: Your code example does not include what t1 and t2 are. t1[0, 0]=1 tries to assign the value 1 to the index (0, 0) of t1. But what is t1?

Comment: Yes, actually t1=loadtxt("t\1.txt") , similar for t2. I have added this part in the problem statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you could either use a dictionary with all your t's or use the exec built in function. **Python 2.x** looks like this:

```
t1 = [1,2,3]
t2 = [1,2,3]
st=0

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(3):
        exec "a = t"+str(i+1)+"["+str(j)+"]"
        st+=a
print st
```

In **Python 3.x** you want to use () for the built in functions. Makes the code look like this:

```
t1 = [1,2,3]
t2 = [1,2,3]
st=0

    for i in range(2):
        for j in range(3):
            exec("a = t"+str(i+1)+"["+str(j)+"]")
            st+=a
    print(st)
```

The exec function will take a string and act like it was a normal line of code and execute it. This way you can assemble your command and let the interpreter do the rest. (Using String Formatting instead of connecting the string with + might be a better approach though)

Comment: But when I run your code, it tells me that "    exec "a = t"+str(i+1)
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: Obviously, because I was giving an example assuming you are using normal variables, not tables like you actually do. I updated my example to fit your a code using tables.

Comment: Somehow the same warning appeared again, "   exec "a = t"+str(i+1)+"["+str(j)+"]"
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax" Is it because the version of python, I am using python 3.4.0

Comment: Sorry I was assuming you are using pythong 2.x. Python 3.x uses () for all built in functions like print and exec. Just to make it really clear I edited my post for 2.x and 3.x . Hope this helps.

Comment: Wonderful solution!! Although a bit slow, I can have a good sleep tonight~

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to do what you want (see link in the comment to your question), but why bother when you can simply do:

```
st = 0
for t in (t1,t2):
    for i in range(3):
        st += t[0,i]
```

Comment: oops, open my mind, but what if I have t1, t2.... t100?

Comment: I think in this case it would be easier to just store the t's as dictionary keys rather than variables.

Comment: I will learn more later~